# Collapsing columns in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need some help to build something like : [this grid](http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_columns_show_hide_columns.aspx)

Instead of hide/collapse the traditional rows, what I want to do is a user control that hide and collapse the columns when I click in the respective buttons.

Appreciated for the help!

Comment: Do you need it to be asynchronous like in the example? The column visible property is something you can manipulate. Other than that, your question is rather broad: consider re-asking with more detail.

Comment: But in that example is described hot to do this, so what's the problem ?

Comment: yes! I want like the example!

I want to build something like the traditional hide/show rows in a datagrid. Instead of clicking in the plus/minor button I want to click in some button in the form.

Comment: What do you have so far and where are the problems?

Answer (score 0):

Well, start looking at how you hide a <table>'s columns with JavaScript for one; but you have to build a client-side API (at least partial) if you want to translate a column to a column name... not an easy task.

A lot of these grids have thousands of lines of code to provide all the features they do, especially from third party controls.